# Transfer learning on MobileNetV3 reaches plateau and I can't move past it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, mobilenet

I'm trying to do transfer learning on MobileNetV3-Small using Tensorflow 2.5.0 to predict dog breeds (133 classes) and since it got reasonable accuracy on the ImageNet dataset (1000 classes) I thought it should have no problem adapting to my problem.

I've tried a multitude of training variations and recently had a breakthrough but now my training stagnates at about 60% validation accuracy with minor fluctuations in validation loss (accuracy and loss curves for training and validation below).

[image: Accuracy and loss curves for training and validation data]

I tried using `ReduceLROnPlateau` in the 3rd graph below, but it didn't help to improve matters. Can anyone suggest how I could improve the training?

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling2D, Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV3Large, MobileNetV3Small
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True # needed for working with this dataset


# define generators
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(vertical_flip=True, horizontal_flip=True,
                                   rescale=1.0/255, brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5],
                                   zoom_range=[0.5, 1.5], rotation_range=90)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size=(224,224),
                                              batch_size=32, class_mode="categorical")
val_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(val_dir, target_size=(224,224),
                                              batch_size=32, class_mode="categorical")
test_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, target_size=(224,224),
                                              batch_size=32, class_mode="categorical")

pretrained_model = MobileNetV3Small(input_shape=(224,224,3), classes=133,
                             weights="imagenet", pooling=None, include_top=False)
# set all layers trainable because when I froze most of the layers the model didn't learn so well
for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
last_output = pretrained_model.layers[-1].output
x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(last_output)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(133, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(pretrained_model.input, x)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-5), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# val_acc with min_delta 0.003; val_loss with min_delta 0.01
plateau = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", mode="min", patience=5,
                            min_lr=1e-8, factor=0.3, min_delta=0.01,
                            verbose=1)
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=savepath, verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                               monitor="val_accuracy", mode="max",
                               save_weights_only=True)
```

Comment: How many epochs are you training for?

Comment: In total, I've trained for about 80 epochs to get the 60% validation accuracy. I've had to reload the weights and restart training a few times because I'm training with Google Colab

Comment: I would guess you have reached the limit of the architecture - try increasing the model parameters or use some more modern CNN implementation like EfficientNet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks good, but it seems to have one issue - you might be rescaling the inputs twice. According to [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/mobilenet_v3/preprocess_input) for MobilenetV3:

> The preprocessing logic has been included in the mobilenet_v3 model implementation. Users are no longer required (...) to normalize the input data.

Now, in your code, there is:
`test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)`
which essentially, makes the first model layers to rescale, already rescaled values.
The same applies for `train_datagen`.

You could try removing the `rescale` argument from both `train` and `test` loaders, or setting `rescale=None`.

This could also explain why the model did not learn well with the backbone frozen.

Comment: Thank you! Now the network is learning after a few epochs rather than 20-30 epochs! I wish I had been more observant when using the tensorflow implementation. Lesson learned: Read the docs!

Comment: Great to hear that you got it working. Cheers!